# Abrir Internet Explorer Selenium en Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

Estoy intentado abrir Internet Explorer mediante Selenium, sin embargo al ejecutar el código éste me abre el navegador Microsoft Edge, el cúal no me sirve ya que quiero trabajar con IE 11 por temas de compatibilidad.

```
from selenium import webdriver    
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path="C:\\Users\\patri\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe")
```

Tengo como aplicaciones predeterminadas IE 11, aún así me sigue abriendo Edge.

Alguna sugerencia para poder ejecutar IE ?, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Seguiste tooodas las indicaciones de las configuraciones que requiere ese driver de acuerdo a [la documentación](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/ie_driver_server/)?

Una traducción libre de esas instrucciones sería:

> #### Configuración requerida
>
> El ejecutable de IEDriverServer debe descargarse y ubicarse en el PATH.
>
> Para IE 7 o superior en Windows Vista, Windows 7 o Windows 10, debe configurar el Protected Mode para cada zona con el mismo valor (puede ser on u off) siempre y cuando sea el mismo en cada zona. Para configurar esto, seleccione “Internet Options…” del menú *Herramientas* y haga clic en la pestaña Seguridad. Para cada zona, habrá un check box al final de la pestaña con la etiqueta “Enable Protected Mode”.
>
> Adicionalmente, “Enhanced Protected Mode” debe deshabilitarse para IE 10 y superior. Esta opción está disponible en la pestaña *Avanzado* del diálogo *Opciones de Internet*.
>
> El zoom en el navegador debe fijarse en 100% para que los eventos de mouse usen las coordenadas correctas.
>
> Para Windows 10, también necesita configurar “Change the size of text, apps, and other items” al 100% en la configuración de pantalla.
>
> Sólo para IE 11, necesita crear una entrada en el Registro de Windows en la terminal objetivo (*de la prueba*) para que el driver pueda mantener una conexión a la instancia de Internet Explorer que crea. Para instalaciones Windows de 32-bit, la clave (key) que debe examinar en el Editor de Registro (regedit) es `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`. Para instalaciones de 64-bit, la clave (key) es `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`. Tenga en cuenta que la subclave (subkey) `FEATURE_BFCACHE` puede o no estar presente **y debe ser creada si no está presente**. **Importante:** Dentro de esta clave (key), cree un valor DWORD llamado `iexplore.exe` con valor `0`.

En el primer punto es importante tener en cuenta que el PATH es el definido para tu usuario o para el entorno del sistema. O pones el exe en uno de los directorios ya incluidos, o añades el directorio con el driver a las rutas que contiene el PATH.

En las instrucciones y configuraciones de seguridad, se sobreentiende que las opciones de menú y diálogos, son de Internet Explorer 11.

La configuración de pantalla que recomiendan es del OS.

El cambio en el registro debe hacerse con cuidado y, si prefieres, puedes crear un backup del registro ANTES de hacer cambios.

Answer (score 0):

He decidido escribir el siguiente código, con el fin de hacer más práctica la ejecución del navegador y utilizar el Modo IE en MicrosoftEdge.

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions
import time
        
        
edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True

#Define la carpeta del perfil de usuario
edge_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\patri\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data")

#Define el usuario que utilizará
edge_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Default")

#Define el .exe de MicrosoftEdge
edge_options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"

#Agrega las opciones anteriores y el Path de msedgedriver.exe
driver = Edge(options = edge_options, executable_path = r"C:\Users\patri\Desktop\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://google.com')
        
time.sleep(20)
driver.quit()
```